# Canvas content in JSON file doesn't load with FabricJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I have this design using in fabric.js in JSON file:

[image]

I want to load this in a canvas, I researched and found that I can do it using **loadFromJSON** , so this is my code:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

$("#setGraph").click(function(){
  
  var settings = {
    "url": "https://amz-rekognition.s3.amazonaws.com/json/demo2.json",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0
    };

  jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    
    var json = JSON.stringify(response);
    console.log(json);
    canvas.clear();
    canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function() {
       canvas.renderAll(); 
    },function(o,object){
       console.log(o,object)
    })

  });


});
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid #CCC;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://amz-rekognition.s3.amazonaws.com/json/fabric.curvedText.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="216" height="216"></canvas>
<button type="button" id="setGraph">insert graph</button>
```

As you can see, It doesn't contain any object on canvas after clicking the button.

[image]

I'd like to receive your help.